# Show your office location on Google Maps

Tags: google-maps

Using Google Maps, I searched for “JBR Dubai” and I found it. Here when I zoom it, I can see all the offices in my tower but I cannot see my office. How I can set my office over there?

I want people to see my office location and title when they zoom in to my tower, so that they can come to view it. Is this possible? And if yes, how?

I am not talking about my places in Google Maps. I read all these links but no luck.

http://google.about.com/od/mapsanddirections/ht/editmaps_ht.htm

Answer (score 5):

Log in on [Places for Business](http://www.google.com/business/placesforbusiness/), then fill out the details, set the correct marker position, and your office will show up on Google Maps.

Answer (score -3):

i Guess this would be alternative way, Browse Your Place in new Google Maps and just upload the picture of your office there, Whenever the user browses the certain point they might view your places in goolge maps .

Alternatively try [Mapmaker](http://www.google.co.in/mapmaker) and update it

Hope it helps

Comment: They add a marker on map,and only visible when you search for your location..I want to add label so when people zoom in that area,it automatically show there..how this can be possible?

Comment: Lonely:I want to place a label type as we have for all other locations